# Navigation Links and the CTA's section problem

Tags: website-design, navigation

Here is the look for the one of the company page inside the website and it has lot to add right now.
[image: One of the website's listed companies page]

On the right side, there is a progress bar of the company which will contain the statistics and below that there is another CTA which is required.

Now according to the new requirements, Clients don't want the Statistics but the CTAs are mandatory.

[image]

And on the left side there is internal page's navigation(side bar navigation like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)). The data is not certain for each company and the side bar will contain different data every time.

[image]

As this diligence guide is way too long so I'm thinking to keep it in 10 columns instead of 7 columns by removing the progress bar but I'm not sure putting it below the left-side-navigation.

Comment: What exactly in the problem referred to in question? Your last sentence tries to get there, but doesn't quite. Can you add a summary statement at the end that clearly states your problem as a question?

Comment: Could you add your actual question? It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: Columns or rows?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the Progress bar and keep the CTA there where they are currently. Or, may add them between the contents of "Diligence Guide" in middle or put them in Left-side-navigation as long as they do not go below the fold!

Answer (score 1):

Separating the call to action buttons from the list on the side helps the button appear to be more than just additional navigation.

If the length of the list is dynamic that means your placement of the calls to action would also be variable and could be pushed off the fold of the screen with a long list.

An option depending on the nature of the call to action and the page could be having the call to action placed inside the center text or having the buttons follow the user as they scroll on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have 3 CTAs on your page, Follow, CTA 1 and CTA 2.
as start, don't put the navigator below the CTAs, cause users' naturally accustomed to find the navigator on the left.
and about CTAs: use different type of button for showing priority of the CTAs, for example use linear button for "follow" action and same buttons for other CTAs'.
good luck